# How to explode strings from three columns and insert to a new table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. I have 3 columns in mysql and in all three columns there are values that are separated with "\n".

I want to explode values from all three columns at the same time and insert data in new table.

Check the example what I am trying to do:

Now:

```
table name: old_machines
-------------------------------------------------
id        | machine          | price             
-------------------------------------------------
 1        | bager            | 1500
          | car              | 2000
          | telehendler      | 3500
          | roller           | 2700
-------------------------------------------------
 2        | truck            | 4000
          | platform         | 1200
-------------------------------------------------
 3        | bager 2          | 1600
-------------------------------------------------
 4        | machine 1        | 2200
          | machine 2        | 2400
          | machine 3        | 3000
```

And I want to explode these values to a new table:

```
table name: new_machines
-------------------------------------------------
id        | machine          | price             
-------------------------------------------------
 1        | bager            | 1500
 2        | car              | 2000
 3        | telehendler      | 3500
 4        | roller           | 2700
 5        | truck            | 4000
 6        | platform         | 1200
 7        | bager 2          | 1600
 8        | machine 1        | 2200
 9        | machine 2        | 2400
 10       | machine 3        | 3000
```

This is what I have tried:

```
$num = 1;

$sql = $con->prepare("SELECT name, price FROM old_machines");
$sql->execute(); 
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {

    $lines = explode("\n", $row['name']);
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $sql1 = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO new_machines (name) VALUES (?)");
        $sql1->execute([$line]);
    }

    $lines = explode("\n", $row['price']);
    foreach($lines as $line) {
        $sql1 = $con->prepare("UPDATE new_machines SET price=? WHERE id=?");
        $sql1->execute([$line, $num]);
        $num++;
    } 
}
```

How to done this in better way?

What if I have much more columns like this?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What exactly is not working? It should not be too hard to debug these simple lines

Comment: My solution is working. But the problem is when I have a thousands of rows, then this solution mix data. So I need a better solution to done this

Comment: So what the problem is? you don't say that and in another comment says that's not about splitting. Please update your question or it will be closed. BTW *hundreds* of rows is not a problem, that's a relatively small table.

Comment: And why you use both `INSERT` and `UPDATE` for each row? It will generate a mess as you already mentioned. Just do it once with `INSERT` and forgot old table

Comment: If your solution is working, but mixing data, then I would not call this "working". So, what have you tried to debug why it does not work?

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over names and prices at the same time.

```
<?php    
$sql = $con->prepare('SELECT name, price FROM old_machines');
$sql->execute();
while ($row = $sql->fetch()) {
    $names  = explode('\n', $row['name']);
    $prices = explode('\n', $row['price']);
    //$names and $prices are arrays, which should have the same indexes and same size
    if (count($names) !== count($prices)) {
        throw new Exception('Names and Prices should have the same number of lines');
    }
    foreach($names as $index => $name) {
        $price = $prices[$index];
        $sql1 = $con->prepare('INSERT INTO new_machines (name, price) VALUES (?, ?)');
        $sql1->execute([$name, $price]);
    }
}
```